# Can't deploy azure db with ansible azure_rm_sqldatabase module

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, ansible

I am trying to deploy Azure Database via `azure_rm_sqldatabase` module

```
- name: Deploy azure DB
  azure_rm_sqldatabase:
    resource_group: "{{ resourceGroupName }}"
    server_name: "{{ sqlServerName }}"
    name: ansible-interactive-test-db
    cert_validation_mode: ignore
```

Below is the error:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "No
>   handlers could be found for logger
>   \"msrestazure.azure_active_directory\"\nTraceback (most recent call
>   last):\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_5wOdgn/ansible_module_azure_rm_sqldatabase.py\", line
>   499, in \n    main()\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_5wOdgn/ansible_module_azure_rm_sqldatabase.py\", line
>   496, in main\n    AzureRMDatabases()\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_5wOdgn/ansible_module_azure_rm_sqldatabase.py\", line
>   312, in **init**\n    supports_tags=False)\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_5wOdgn/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/azure_rm_common.py\",
>   line 384, in **init**\n  File
>   \"/tmp/ansible_5wOdgn/ansible_module_azure_rm_sqldatabase.py\", line
>   395, in exec_module\n    response = self.create_update_sqldatabase()\n
>   File \"/tmp/ansible_5wOdgn/ansible_module_azure_rm_sqldatabase.py\",
>   line 438, in create_update_sqldatabase\n
>   parameters=self.parameters)\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/mgmt/sql/operations/databases_operations.py\", line 344, in create_or_update\n    **operation_config\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/azure/mgmt/sql/operations/databases_operations.py\", line 286, in _create_or_update_initial\n    body_content =
>   self._serialize.body(parameters, 'Database')\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/serialization.py\", line
>   564, in body\n    SerializationError, \"Unable to build a model:
>   \"+str(err), err)\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/msrest/exceptions.py\", line 57, in
>   raise_with_traceback\n    raise
>   error\nmsrest.exceptions.SerializationError: Unable to build a model:
>   Unable to deserialize response data. Data: Disabled, bool, TypeError:
>   Invalid boolean value: Disabled, DeserializationError: Unable to
>   deserialize response data. Data: Disabled, bool, TypeError: Invalid
>   boolean value: Disabled\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE
>   FAILURE", "rc": 1}

I tried to update `azure-cli-core to 2.0.42` and `msrestazure to 0.4.34` but didn't work.

Ansible version is `2.6.1`

Before that I could azure resource group and azure database server with no error.

Comment: what means "Before that I am creating azure resource group and azure database server with no error"? do you mean you successfully launched the same task before ?

Comment: I have playbook where I am creating resource group, azure database server and azure database ... first two tasks are ok, but deploy database shows error ... so connection to azure should be ok (at least for two first tasks)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems that it is working now. I used the same script and now I can create azure sql database

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on how you fixed it? Did you reboot your computer?